# MySQL error #1064 while inserting

Tags: mysql

i've been looking at this for quite some time and i can't figure out what is wrong. im trying to insert a new row into my table but i keep getting the #1064 error when trying to do so. im new to this so it might be blatantly obvious to some of you...

here is my insert code:

```
INSERT INTO registration (`fname`, `lname`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, 
                          `state`, `zcode`, `dob_mon`, `dob_day`, `dob_year`, 
                          `email`, `number`, `gender`)
                  VALUES (`joe`, `bob`, `123 abc`, `apt 209`, `la`, 
                          `CA`, `99999`, `JUN`, `14`, `1999`, 
                          `a@gmail.com`, `1234567`, `F')
```

and here is part of my php file

```
$fields = "`". implode("`, `", array_keys($register_data)) ."`";
$data = "`". implode("`, `", $register_data) ."'";
echo "INSERT INTO `registration` ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use angled quotes for values. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO registration (`fname`, `lname`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zcode`, `dob_mon`, `dob_day`, `dob_year`, `email`, `number`, `gender`) VALUES ('joe', 'bob', '123 abc', 'apt 209', 'la', 'CA', '99999', 'JUN', '14', '1999', 'a@gmail.com', '1234567', 'F')
```

Comment: Good news eml002. If that solved your issue, the please tick the green arrow.